# Docker-compose local volume mount osx

Tags: macos, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, grav

I am trying to create a simple local docker setup with Grav CMS (getgrav.org).

I have successfully gotten the docker container to spin up and server me the proper files, however when I try to create a mounted volume for the "user" directory of the CMS things seem to break.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-apache

RUN set -xe \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/grav/.unpacked \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng12-0 git unzip libpng12-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite

ENV GRAV_URL "https://getgrav.org/download/core/grav/1.3.3"

RUN set -xe \
    && curl -fSL -o /usr/src/grav/grav.zip "$GRAV_URL" \
    && unzip /usr/src/grav/grav.zip -d /usr/src/grav/.unpacked \
    && rm /usr/src/grav/grav.zip \
    && mv /usr/src/grav/.unpacked/*/* /usr/src/grav \
    && mv /usr/src/grav/.unpacked/*/.[!.]* /usr/src/grav \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/grav/.unpacked \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/grav \
    && cd /usr/src/grav \
        && bin/gpm selfupgrade -y \
        && bin/gpm install -y admin git-sync

VOLUME /var/www/html

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:

  grav:
    image: grav
    container_name: gravdocker
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: gravlocal.docker
```

and my docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -z "$(ls -A /var/www/html)"]; then
    cp -a /usr/src/grav/. /var/www/html/
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
        if [ "$GRAV_REVERSE_PROXY" = "true" ]; then
        sed -i "s/reverse_proxy_setup:\sfalse/reverse_proxy_setup: true/g" \
        system/config/system.yaml
    fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

With this setup everything is okay. When I add

```
volumes:
  - ./user:/var/www/html/user
```

to the docker-compose file, I get a forbidden error in the browser. When I try to specify another volume in the dockerfile for the user directory it also gives me a forbidden warning in the browser.

My goal is to have the CMS running in docker and listening for a user directory locally so I can do theme development and have a local version of the files.

Comment: I have tried adding 

volumes:
  - ./user:/var/www/html/user

and that always overwrites the entire directory of var/www/html and not just user.

Comment: After running docker-compose up, try running `docker-compose exec grav chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I actually somewhat figured out what the issue is. 

In my docker-compose.yml when I add the lines:

`volumes:
  - ./user:/var/www/html/user`

it actually replaces the whole /html/ directory with an empty user directory instead of just appending the user directory. Do I need to add something to docker-entrypoint.sh to possible avoid that?

Comment: Actually if you map a child directory then parent should not be impacted. Make sure without mapping `/var/www/html` is not empty. If it is not empty and it is showing empty then it is a bug in docker, you should report it

Comment: So currently, if I add the volumes line to the docker-compose file - the directory is empty sans the /user/ directory that I am adding as a volume

removing that line from docker-compose and everything is working as intended (but the directory is obviously served only from the container)

@TarunLalwani you are thinking this is a bug from docker?

Comment: This looks like a bug, but to confirm what is the output of `tree -L2 /var/www/html` with and without the volume mapping? please add to your question the outputs